# Using the right tense for a future scheduled and planned action

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

I need a piece of advise. Look at these two sentences below.
I'm talking about a **planned** and **scheduled** event for the future regarding a third person (my director), and I'm unsure about the right tense to use.

> My director **flies** to Milan on Saturday at  9.45 A.M.

vs

> My director **is flying** to Milan on Saturday at  9.45 A.M.

Personally, using my not native ear,  I think that the second sentence fits better than the first one, despite the clear time table.

What's your take on this? And why?

Comment: The second sentence definitely sounds better. Though I would personally replace ***on*** with ***this*** to make it sound more specific and split the sentence into two: ***My director is flying to Milan this Saturday. The plane takes off at 9:45 AM.***

Comment: Precious advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine. "Is flying" is more colloquial, and would be appropriate in most contexts. "Flies" might be found in a formal report to management, or a schedule listing various things that are to happen.